# How to align two items horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

Hi I will like to know how can I align an h2 and p horizontally and vertically.

```
.bg-text {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }

  span {
 display: block;
 }
<section class="Home">

  <h1>TEXT</h1>
  <p>More Text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you wrap the tags in another element, like a div?

Comment: Yes, it can use a div

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the elements in a tag, like a `div`, then you can use `transform` to center the element both horizontally and vertically, like this:

```css
html,
body,
section.Home {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="Home">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it dosnt work on my code, i put my code in the description

Comment: Did you wrap the `h2` and `p` in a `<div>` with a class of `centered`?

Comment: Yes, i copied your code, but i have a big space betwen the h2 and the p

Comment: Did you add the CSS to set the margin and padding for the `h2` and `p` elements to `0`?

Comment: The body has margin 0 and padding 0

Comment: By default most browsers will give `h2` and `p` elements some margin and/or padding, so you need to reset those to eliminate the extra spacing.

Comment: You must have some other CSS being applied. You'll need to provide a more complete example.

Comment: Thank you very much I figured out deleting more code i had

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the other techniques here, you can use flexbox with a combination of `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`.

This is a good article on centering stuff https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>H2</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dang that's clean. I'm noting this one.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to use with padding or height or something else...there is many ways to do so.

Here one example how to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.holder{
width:500px;
height:500px
}
.text{
background-color:green;
text-align:center;
padding:50% 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "holder">
<div class="text">
<h1>Hello man</h1>
<p> text text text text</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

There you have all info about it...

Comment: I tried it but it dosnt say how to do it why 2 diferent tags

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? You can use `transform: translateY(-50%);` to achieve that look.

Example:

```
<div class='bg'>
   <div class='bg-text'>
     <h1>Climate.IQ® Team <span>Other text here</span></h1>
   </div>
</div>


.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.bg-text {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y58hu6tv/3/

Answer (score 0):

I made some edits to your example to make it work.

HTML:

```
<section class="home">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
  <p>More Text</p>
</section>
```

It's standard to keep class names in HTML lowercase.

CSS:

```
.home {
  height: 100px;

  /* Internet Explorer 10 */
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;

  /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

  /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

  /* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;
}

p, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKrxbo)

Comment: It has the two elements side by side, I need them one under the other, but <br> dosnt work

Comment: @Bryan I updated the code so that the elements are stacked.